# How to change shiny dashboard footer color

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

[image]

this is my snippet of Shiny Dashboard that I made with R and what I'm trying to do is to change the footer color that I highlight with a red marker, so I want to change it to white so it can blend with the body and I don't know exactly how to do that am I need a CSS file to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to use a combination of `bs4Dash` https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/ and `CSS`:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    title = "Basic Dashboard",
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
    footer = dashboardFooter(
      left = a(
        href = "https://twitter.com/divadnojnarg",
        target = "_blank", "@DivadNojnarg",
      ),
      right = "2020"
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          ".main-footer {
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
          }
          .main-footer a {
            color: white;
          }"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

[image]